# What is an elephant number afterall?

Tags: c++, numbers

I am writing this question putting myself at **risk of massive down voting**. But I still want to risk it as I was really curious and I want to know what's an elephant number.

2 days ago, there was a new user who posted a question on [How to tell if a number is an elephant number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819346/how-to-tell-if-a-number-is-an-elephant-number)

He mentioned that this was asked in his interview.

For those who have seen this question before it was deleted, could you please tell me what is an elephant number??

Comment: My guess would be a number that is too large to represent in a standard integral type (`char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`), but that is just a guess.

Comment: 'If you begin to see elephants dancing and singing during a performance, then that part of the play is what is referred to as an "elephant number"' (c) @0x499602D2

Comment: [Here's the original question.](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:6hJQdVJh6qsJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/22819346/how-to-tell-if-a-number-is-an-elephant-number+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=cawebcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:6hJQdVJh6qsJ:stackoverflow.com/questions/22819346/how-to-tell-if-a-number-is-an-elephant-number+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca) I would guess that they would cast the int to a boolean, but it seems like a badly phrased question.

Comment: This somehow reminds me of this question: [Proper use cases for Android UserManager.isUserAGoat()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375357/proper-use-cases-for-android-usermanager-isuseragoat)

Comment: I would recommend asking in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ next time you are curious about mod action (since deletions are triggered by mods IIRC).

Comment: @Guvante The question doesn't seem to be about mod action, just the definition of an elephant number. And since I too saw the original question and am curious, +1.

Comment: The question was put on hold by ordinary user actions; it was deleted with a diamond moderator as the second voter.  There was no answer forthcoming.  I think it is fair to say that the interviewee should immediately ask the interviewer "I don't think I've heard of an elephant number; how are elephant numbers defined?".

Comment: Could this be the root of an elephant number: http://magic.about.com/od/libraryofsimpletricks/a/mentalpredict.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I might have found out the possible answer to my own question after a long search.

**An interview question on finding maximum number of elephants lived:**
(Click the blue link below)
[Given the life time of different elephants, find the period when maximum number of elephants lived](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483213/given-the-life-time-of-different-elephants-find-the-period-when-maximum-number?rq=1)

I want to share it with all those who are curious like me!

(P.S: I am thankful..till now.. my question has not been voted to -10!)

Answer (score 3):

Questions usually don't get deleted, so I would assume that there is no answer to this. Anecdotally, Google refuses to bring up any programming reference to that phrase in the first two pages.

However I could guess what the answer to the question was:

Ask

Many times while programming you are given incomplete information (in fact in nearly every case).

If I had asked that question during an interview I would expect the interviewee to extract the information they needed from me. In this case it appears that they made a question that was impossible to answer on purpose, that way you know they need to ask you for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As the original question was to implement a function

```
public boolean isElephant(int elephant){...}
```

I would have guessed that `int elephant` **is** an elephant number, because if it wasn't, it wouldn't be called `elephant`, would it?

So, my answer would be:

```
public boolean isElephant(int elephant){ return true; }
```